# asp.net core SignInAsync method not Authenticating

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I have [authorize] attribute at the top of my admin controller.  When I run the following code from my sign in page:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, vm.Email)
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, 
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
```

Everything runs fine.  However it doesn't seem to be signing in the user because the admin controller sends the user back to the sign in page and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false`.

EDIT: Here are my `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
        // options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddDbContext<myDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDb")));

    services.AddScoped<AccountsRepository>();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Home/SignOut");
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```